# Java-EE database connection pool runs out of max

Tags: database, asynchronous, jakarta-ee, transactions

I have a default standalone.xml configuration where there is a maximum of 20 connections to be active at the same time in the pool of connections to the database. With good reasons, I guess. We run an Oracle database.

There's a reasonable amount of database traffic as there is third party API traffic, e.g. SOAP and HTTP calls in the enterprise application I'm developing.

We often do something like the following:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "some-pu")
private EntityManager em;

public void someBusinessMethod() {
    someEntity = em.findSomeEntity();
    soap.callEndPoint(someEntity.getSomeProperty()); // may take up to 1 minute
    em.update(someEntity);
    cdiEvent.fire(finishedBusinessEvent);
}
```

However, in this case the database connection is acquired when the entity is fetched and is released after the update (actually when the entire transaction is done). About transactions, everything is container managed, no additional annotations. I know that you shouldn't "hold" the database connection longer than necessary, and this is exactly what I'm trying to solve. For one I wouldn't know how to programmatically release the connection nor do I think it would be a good idea, because you still want to be able to roll back for the entire transaction.

So? How to attack this problem? There's a number of options I tried:

Option 1, using `ManagedExecutorService`:

```
@Resource
private ManagedExecutorService mes;

public void someBusinessMethod() {
    someEntity = em.findSomeEntity();

    this.mes.submit(() -> {
        soap.callEndPoint(someEntity.getSomeProperty()); // may take up to 1 minute
        em.update(someEntity);
        cdiEvent.fire(finishedBusinessEvent);
    });
}
```

Option 2, using `@Asynchronous`:

```
@Inject
private AsyncBean asyncBean;

public void someBusinessMethod() {
    someEntity = em.findSomeEntity();
    this.asyncBean.process(someEntity);
}

public class AsyncBean {

    @Asynchronous
    public void process() {
        soap.callEndPoint(someEntity.getSomeProperty()); // may take up to 1 minute
        em.update(someEntity);
        cdiEvent.fire(finishedBusinessEvent);
    }

}
```

This in fact solved the database connection pooling issue, e.g. the connection is released as soon as the `soap.callEndPoint` happened. But it did not feel really stable (can't pinpoint the problems here). And of course the transaction is finished once you enter the a-sync processing, so whenever something went wrong during the soap call there was nothing roll backed.

**wrapping up...**
I'm about to move the long running IO tasks (soap and http calls) to a separate part of the application offloaded via queue's and feeding the result back in the application via queue's once again. In this case everything is done via transactions and no connections are held up. But this is a lot of overhead, thus before doing so I'd like to hear your opinion / best practices how to solve this problem!

Comment: How many concurrent web requests are executing normally and at peak?

Comment: About 50 to 100, at peak around 200. Wildfly is configured to wait about 30 seconds before failing on acquiring a connection from the pool. No retries.

Comment: What's your strategy for dealing with concurrent changes to the same entity?

Answer (score 0):

Your queue solution is viable, but perhaps not necessary if you only perform read operations before your calls, you could split the transaction into 2 transactions  (as you would also do with the queue) by using a DAO pattern.

Example:

```
@Stateless
private DaoBean dao;

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
public void someBusinessMethod() {
    Entity e = dao.getEntity(); // creates and discards TX
    e = soap.callEndPoint(e.getSomeProperty());
    dao.update(e); // creates TX 2 and commits
}
```

This solutions has a few caveats.

- The business method above can not be called while a transaction is already active because it would negate the purpose of the DAO (one TX suspended with NOT_SUPPORTED).
- You will have to handle or ignore the possible changes that could have occurred on the entity during the soap call (@Version ...).
- The entity will be detached in the business method, so you will have to eager load everything you need in the soap call.

I can't tell you if this would work for you as it depends on what is done before the business call. While still complex, it would be easier than a queue.

Comment: I do enter a transaction right away, so I doubt your purposed solution would actually work :-(. Would a `@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)` on the `dao.getEntity()` help have it in its own transaction and discard it once it finished fetching it from the database (dirty read)? Therefor no connection is held when doing the soap call. Still, I would need to implement @Version for possible conflicts..

Answer (score 0):

You were kind of heading down the right track with Option 2, it just needs a little more decomposition to get the transaction management happening in a way that keeps them very short.

Since you have a potentially long running web service call you're definitely going to need to perform your database updates in two separate transactions:

1. short find operation
2. long web service call
3. short update operation

This can be accomplished by introducing a third EJB as follows:

> *Entry point*

```
@Stateless
public class MyService {

    @Inject
    private AsyncService asyncService;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    /*
     * Short lived method call returns promptly
     * (unless you need a fancy multi join query)
     * It will execute in a short REQUIRED transaction by default
     */
    public void someBusinessMethod(long entityId) {
        SomeEntity someEntity = em.find(SomeEntity.class, entityId);
        asyncService.process(someEntity);
    }

}
```

> *Process web service call*

```
@Stateless
public class AsyncService {

    @Inject
    private BusinessCompletionService businessCompletionService;

    @Inject
    private SomeSoapService soap;

    /*
     * Long lived method call with no transaction.
     *
     * Asynchronous methods are effectively run as REQUIRES_NEW
     * unless it is disabled.
     * This should avoid transaction timeout problems.
     */
    @Asynchronous
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void process(SomeEntity someEntity) {
        soap.callEndPoint(someEntity.getSomeProperty()); // may take up to 1 minute
        businessCompletionService.handleBusinessProcessCompletion(someEntity);
    }
}
```

> *Finish up*

```
@Stateless
public class BusinessCompletionService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    @Any
    private Event<BusinessFinished> businessFinishedEvent;

    /*
     * Short lived method call returns promptly.
     * It defaults to REQUIRED, but will in effect get a new transaction
     * for this scenario.
     */
    public void handleBusinessProcessCompletion(SomeEntity someEntity) {
        someEntity.setSomething(SOMETHING);
        someEntity = em.merge(someEntity);
        // you may have to deal with optimistic locking exceptions...
        businessFinishedEvent.fire(new BusinessFinished(someEntity));
    }

}
```

I suspect that you may still need some connection pool tuning to cope effectively with your peak load. Monitoring should clear that up.